# How to retrieve the last message from Quickblox in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, quickblox

I send message to the chat dialog but I am not able to retreive the last messages.

How to get the the last messages from the chat dialog with a certain ID and and forwards it to the recipient for iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have been joined the room, just access `lastMessageText` directly:

```
dialog.lastMessageText
```

Or get the last message with a certain ID using `QBRequest`:

```
QBRequest.messagesWithDialogID("ID",
    extendedRequest: ["sort_desc" : "date_sent", "limit" : 1],
    forPage: nil,
    successBlock: { (response, messages, page) -> Void in
        println(messages)
    },
    errorBlock: { (response) -> Void in
        println(response)
    }
)
```

Comment: thanks but do you know i to get online/offline user from quickblox